# tcl file rename and catching error if file exists

Tags: file, try-catch, tcl, rename

I'm a newbie, and I'm trying to append the .skip extension to some files taken from a list of file names in TCL. In case a file with fileName.skip already exists, I would like to catch the error, put my own message on the screen, and continue to the next file. Here is the code I am using:

```
set i 0
foreach fileName [glob -nocomplain -type f [file join $basedir *.wav]] {
    foreach line $fileData {
        if { [regexp $line $fileName] == 1 } {
            if { [catch {file rename $fileName "$fileName.skip"}] } {
                puts "Error skipping $fileName skipped file already exists"
                continue
            } else {
                puts "Skipping $fileName..."
                file rename [file join $basedir $fileName] [file join $basedir "$fileName.skip"]
                incr i
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I have three files in my folder that I'm testing on:

```
test21.wav
test21.wav.skip
test22.wav
```

This code executes to the point where it renames (or does not rename) the files, but then it prints this to the screen:

```
Error skipping C:/xxx/test21.wav file already exists
Skipping C:/xxx/test22.wav...
error renaming "C:/xxx/test22.wav": no such file or directory
    while executing
"file rename $fileName "$fileName.skip""
```

I can't seem to figure out what this error is about, since the script works. Is it that I'm using `catch` incorrectly? Or maybe it's something else....

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You renamed the file twice: once at the `if` command, another in the else block. You don't need to the `file rename` command in the else block.

The way the `catch` command works is this:

1. Execute the block of code
2. If the execution failed, return 1. If success, return 0

So, in your context:

```
set i 0
foreach fileName [glob -nocomplain -type f [file join $basedir *.wav]] {
    foreach line $fileData {
        if { [regexp $line $fileName] == 1 } {
            if { [catch {file rename $fileName "$fileName.skip"}] } {
                # Rename failed
                puts "Error skipping $fileName skipped file already exists"
            } else {
                # Renamed OK
                puts "Skipping $fileName..."
                incr i
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm still missing something here... the `catch` command actually does execute my command? Is there a better way to catch the error WITHOUT executing the command, so that I can increment my counter only in the case that the command is executed?

Comment: Did you mean *increment my counter only in the case that the command is executed* **successfully**? You have that already. Just remove the second `file rename` in the else block.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just see if it exists first?

```
set i 0
foreach fileName [glob -nocomplain -type f [file join $basedir *.wav]] {
    foreach line $fileData {
        if {[regexp $line $fileName]} {
            if {[file exists "$fileName.skip"]} {
                puts "Error skipping $fileName -- skipped file already exists"
                continue
            } else {
                puts "Skipping $fileName..."
                set filepath [file join $basedir $fileName]
                file rename $filepath $filepath.skip
                incr i
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Since it appears that `$fileData` contains a list of strings, you don't need the inner foreach loop. [`lsearch`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) will work here:

```
set i 0
foreach fileName [glob -nocomplain -type f [file join $basedir *.wav]] {
    if {[lsearch -regexp $fileData $fileName] != -1} {
        if {[file exists "$fileName.skip"]} {
            puts "Error skipping $fileName -- skipped file already exists"
        } else {
            puts "Skipping $fileName..."
            set filepath [file join $basedir $fileName]
            file rename $filepath $filepath.skip
            incr i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great answer, and looks more like what I meant to do... but since my question title addresses `catch` I will keep the other answer selected in case other people search for something about `catch`.